# jquery.on("click") doens't work as i expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am building a web app. the main navigation of this web app is refreshed with jquery but after the refresh the jquery event doesnt work.

the "on button" has a jquery event bound to it with *.on* and everytime it is clicked it will append a paragraph. the "reset button" adds another "on button" but the jquery event doesn't apply to it.

i have used the *.on* method to circumvent that the second "on button" isn't in the DOM when the document is ready.

here is a simple example:

[example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GzvRu/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>blub</title>

<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".reset").click(function() {
            $("nav").append('<button class="on">test</button>');
        })

        var count = 0;
        $(".on").on("click", function(){
            $(".cont").append("<p>Another paragraph! "+(++count)+"</p>");
        });

    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <button class="reset">reset</button>
    <nav>
        <button class="on">test</button>
    </nav>
    <div class="cont"></div>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.on` isn't a direct replacement for `.live`, its syntax is slightly different.  If you want it to affect elements added to the DOM later, you need to use it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.on', function(){
});
```

Comment: ah yes, i tried to use it like .live. thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The problem is hot you use method "on" try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".reset").click(function() {
            $("nav").append('<button class="on">test</button>');
        })

        var count = 0;
        $(document).on("click",".on", function(){
            $(".cont").append("<p>Another paragraph! "+(++count)+"</p>");
        });

    });
</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GzvRu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it very simply this way -- this way the click handler gets assigned to each button as it is created.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var count = 0;

    $(".reset").click(function() {
        $("nav").append($('<button>', {
            class: 'on',
            html: 'test',
            click: function() {
                $('.cont').append('<p>Another paragraph! ' + (++count) + '</p>');
            }
        }));
    });
});
```